# Is a TCP connection considered idle if there still un-ACK'd packets?

Tags: tcp

1. Is a TCP connection considered idle if there still un-ACK'd packets?
2. Is TCP considered idle if the RECV buffer is full on the server side and is unable to accept more data for let's say 500 seconds and the idle timeout is only 300 seconds?
3. Is the idle timeout only possible on the client-side or the server side can do it as well?

Comment: To get a useful answer you are probably going to have to add more detail or code.  I am not aware of any precise definition of "idle."  I'm guessing you are asking about the behavior of TCP_USER_TIMEOUT under various conditions.  If so, check out [this blog post about the interaction of TCP_USER_TIMEOUT and SO_KEEPALIVE](https://blog.cloudflare.com/when-tcp-sockets-refuse-to-die/), although standards compliant TCP implementations could well differ from what they describe.

Comment: Define 'idle' and 'idle timeout'. These are not concepts in TCP.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a TCP connection considered idle if there still un-ACK'd packets?

Depends on the perspective. From the perspective of the application it matters if it sends or receives data, i.e. state of ACK does not matter. From the perspective of a packet filter firewall in between it matters if packets are exchanged, no matter if with payload or without (i.e. TCP keep-alive). 
From the perspective of an OS kernel the idle timeout is much longer than it would wait for an ACK.

> Is TCP considered idle if the RECV buffer is full on the server side and is unable to accept more data for let's say 500 seconds and the idle timeout is only 300 seconds?

This is only relevant from the perspective of the OS kernel. If an ACK is outstanding for this long the connection would not be treated as idle but as broken.

> Is the idle timeout only possible on the client-side or the server side can do it as well?

Each site can do their own in the OS, in the application and there can be idle timeouts in firewalls in between. They all are independent and can all be different.